# $a$ and $b$ are nonzero unequal real numbers and $\frac{a-b}{a}=\frac{b}{a-b}$, what is the sum of all possible values for $\frac{a}{b}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $a$ and $b$ are nonzero unequal real numbers and $\frac{a-b}{a}=\frac{b}{a-b}$, what is the sum of all possible values for $\frac{a}{b}$?

---

I have tried cross-multiplying (which works since $a\neq b$), but all I ended up getting was $a^2-3ab+b^2=0$, which I can't figure out how to use to my benefit. Other than this, I can only think of bashing out possibilities, but I'll probably miss something if I do that. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: $$x=a/b$$ $$x^2-3x+1=0$$

Comment: Does solving the quadratic in terms of either $a$ or $b$ do any good?

Comment: @mr_e_man: how did you get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Take the fractions on both sides, and divide the top and bottom by $b$:
$$
\frac{a-b}{a} = \frac{b}{a-b} \implies \frac{(a/b)-(b/b)}{a/b} = \frac{(b/b)}{(a/b)-(b/b)}\\
\implies \frac{x - 1}{x} = \frac{1}{x - 1},
$$
where $x = a/b$.

Alternatively, taking your expanded equation $a^2-3ab+b^2=0$ and dividing both sides by $b^2$ gets you the same result.